# Ignore timezone when posting value from Angular app to .Net Core WebAPI

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am posting the following JSON from my `Angular` application, to a `.Net Core WebAPI`:

```
{CompanyBillingHireRateId: 4, CompanyId: 44, AccountId: null, EquipmentId: 128, EffectiveDate: Sun Dec 29 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)}
```

As you can see, the value of the `EffectiveDate` is as follow: `EffectiveDate: Sun Dec 29 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)`

Below is my .Net Core controller method:

```
[HttpPut("billing/hirerates/update")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateNewCompanyBillingHireRateAsync([FromBody] CompanyBillingHireRateViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var success = await _companyFacade.UpdateCompanyBillingHireRates_Async(model).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (success)
                return Created("", success);
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        catch (CustomException cEx)
        {
            await _customExceptionProcess.ProcessCustomException(cEx).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return StatusCode(cEx.StatusCode, new { Message = cEx.FriendlyMessage ?? "" });
        }
    }
```

Within my .Net application, the `EffectiveDate` is received as: `{2019/12/28 22:00:00 +00:00}`

In my `Startup.cs`, I am trying to configure the API to ignore timezone, and preserve the received date value as is, and convert to corresponding `datetime` in .Net, but failing to do so. Here is my Startup,cs configuration:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(setup =>
        {
            setup.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            setup.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            setup.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
            setup.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.None;
            setup.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        });
```

How can I configure the API to ignore timezones, and just read the JSON value as string, and parse to corresponding date received from Angular UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to solve this problem for my project:

Since Angular runs in the browser, and your browser uses `local time`, I changed my API to handle this accordingly, as follow:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(setup =>
        {
            setup.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            setup.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            setup.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Comment: In .NET 4.8 you could do this in Application_Start() of Global.config.cs like this: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `toISOString()` that converts your client Date into the standard [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Your date will look like:

```
new Date().toISOString()
"2020-04-15T12:55:28.344Z"
```

Where the ending "Z" is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset.
As a general rule, you should always work with UTC dates on the server side and let the client deal with its timezone (unless you have other special requirements).

Unless I misunderstood your question, passing a date already in UTC to the server should be enough without having to change the backend.

---

**Updated**

Based on the comment I see two possible cases then:

1 - Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) that gives you many methods to parse and validate dates. You can parse the date to a UTC date on the client (snippet belows comes from moment.js docs).

If you want to work with a date in the context of the user's local time:

```
moment('2016-01-01T23:35:01'); 
// "2016-01-01T23:35:01-06:00" - UTC offset as the client
```

If you wish to interact with the date as a UTC date, use `moment.utc`:

```
moment.utc('2016-01-01T23:35:01');
// "2016-01-01T23:35:01+00:00" -  Date with a utc offset of +0:00:
```

If you have to work elsewehere with dates, moment.js can be useful, even if it adds some overtime head to your app.

2 - You can add a readonly property on you model that returns an ISOString from your data property.

```
// In xxx.model.ts
get isoStringDate() {
   modelDateProperty.toISOString();
}
```

So you do not have to change all the parts where the model is used, but eventually only the contract to the server with an additional string property.

Comment: The problem is, I am building up a model in the Angular application, that gets posted to the server.  This approach would require me to change all of my properties of type Date, to type string in the Agnular app